# no permission to modify boot file rc.local

Tags: command-line, permissions, screensaver

I'm trying to add a program path `/usr/bin/xscreensaver-demo`, to file so my screensaver will start at boot. But I can't save it. I don't have the permission to change it and save it.
I have tried this in both Brackets and gedit.

`/etc/rc.local`:

```sh
# By default this script does nothing
/usr/bin/xscreensaver-demo
exit 0
```

I thought of using a `sudo` command in the terminal but I don't know what command to execute to edit that file with superuser privilege and save it.

Comment: FYI `/etc/rc.local` probably isn't going to work for a screensaver application - look at [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) instead

Comment: This worked for me in a very simpler way thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need a text editor. Ubuntu comes with gedit by default. To run gedit with sudo privileges type `sudo gedit filepath` . Then you'll be asked for your sudo password, enter it and gedit window will open allowing you to edit and save the file.

If you know how to use vi/vim (even knowing how to insert/save and quit is enough) you can do the same by `sudo vi filepath` This opens the file in your terminal.

Seems that i'm pretty wrong here.

Courtesy of @[steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

@[GTRONICK](https://askubuntu.com/users/282410/gtronick) says >   For gtk applications you should use `gksudo` .

Comment: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Comment: For gtk applications you should use `gksudo`.